# Is there any way in GO HTML Templating to print values from two array of Struct in single row?

Tags: go, html-templates, go-html-template

I have two arrays `A` and `B`, and I want to print their values individually in each row.
When I loop over them separately it actually mess up the row data.

```
<tr style='mso-yfti-irow:2'>
{{ range $ADetail := $A }}
<td width=330 valign=top colspan=2 style='width:301.25pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
                                                                      mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
    <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:13.5pt'>
        <span style='sans-serif;color:#7F7F7F'>{{ $ADetail.Name }}</o:p></span>
    </p>
</td>
<td width=330 valign=top colspan=2 style='width:301.25pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
                                                                      mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
    <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:13.5pt'>
        <span style='sans-serif;color:#7F7F7F'>{{ $ADetail.Value }}</o:p></span>
    </p>
</td>
{{ end }} {{ range $BDetails := $B }}
<td width=330 colspan=3 valign=top style='width:301.25pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
                                                                      mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
    <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:13.5pt'>
        <span style='sans-serif;color:#7F7F7F'>{{ $BDetails.IPAddress }}</o:p></span>
    </p>
</td>
<td width=330 valign=top style='width:301.25pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
                                                                      mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
    <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:13.5pt'>
        <span style='sans-serif;color:#7F7F7F'>{{ $BDetails.Enabled }}</o:p></span>
    </p>
</td>
<td width=330 valign=top style='width:301.25pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
                                                                      mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
    <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:13.5pt'>
        <span style='sans-serif;color:#7F7F7F'>{{ $BDetails.IPv6 }}</o:p></span>
    </p>
</td>
{{ end }}
```

Iterating over two arrays seperatly, actually print second array fully and than go back to first one.

Expected Output: [image]

Comment: Loop over A with index and value, and use that index to get B values.

Comment: What if the size of both arrays are not the same @BurakSerdar

Comment: Then what do you expect the output to be? Maybe I understood your question wrong. What do A and B look like, and what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: It just skip once any array length go out of range and print empty columns.

Comment: Are there multiple rows? Do all the rows have the same number of columns? If not, there will be empty columns in the end.

Comment: Yes multiple rows but with same no of columns.

Comment: Then what you described should not happen, unless len(A)+len(B) are different for some rows

Comment: Let me rephrase, These are an array of structs. I want to Iterate over both and print their values in a single row one by one.

Comment: Yes, that is evident from the code, but what the output is, and what you want the output to be are not.

Comment: I added the Expected output image in the question.

Comment: Outside the template, zip A and B together in a new single array that contains a struct holding both A and B.  Then, in the template, you can `range` over one array, pulling `$Detail.A.Value` `$Detail.B.Enabled` etc in the same iteration.

Comment: Zipping Arrays outside HTML worked. Thanks to both of you!